# Will the Canon Pixma MX882 Wireless Multifunction Printer allow you to keep printing once one ink cartridge has run out?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, ink, canon-pixma

My wife's Epson Workforce 600 has died, and I'm thinking of replacing it with a Canon Pixma MX882 printer/scanner/copier/fax.  One of the most annoying things about the Epson is that once it has decided that one of the ink cartridges is empty, it will not let you print anything until the empty cartridge is replaced.

I have a Canon IP1800 that will let you print until a cartridge *actually* runs out of ink, and even when a cartridge is depleted, I can continue to print using the other colors. (The driver allows you to print using only the color cartridges or using only the black cartridge.)

Questions:

1. Will the Canon Pixma MX882 allow me to print until the ink runs out or will it declare the cartridge empty while ink is still left?
2. Will the Canon Pixma MX882 allow me to keep printing even after one of the cartridges has been used up?

Answer (score 1):

1. It will warn you and you will have to manually select the override button when the ink is low. Its no biggy, just select the OK button that you acknowledge the low ink and it will print until there is no ink left. For us, we get about 10-20 more prints from a dead cartridge.
2. This is really the same question as the first. Yes it will.
3. This printer uses Ink really really fast in comparison to Epson and HP.
4. Another major flaw is even when you are printing in Black and White the printer still uses your color cartridges.